# How do I add a div under a right floated div?

Tags: html, css

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="panel">My Panel</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    background-color: #000;
    margin: 130px auto;
    min-height: 320px;
    width: 940px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0px 10px;
 }

.left {
    width: 600px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    float: left;
 }

.right {
    width: 320px;
    height: 100% auto; 
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: blue;
    float: right;
}

.panel {
    background-color: red;
}
```

### Question:

How can I add another div that I can place under `div.right`? The div that I want to place under `.right` will be `.under_right` and the CSS is:

```
.under_right {
    width: 320px;
    height: 100% auto; 
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: gold;
}
```

Comment: What you want? Can you show me a screenshot?

Comment: @NOX see this http://jsfiddle.net/daQ22/   I need the gold div to come right under the blue div.

Comment: I saw the fiddle, I want you to visualize me the final thing you want. Maybe in Photoshop or Paint you can do it. In this case, I can write the correct HTML/CSS code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/daQ22/2/

Add:

```
clear:both;
float:right;
```

to under_right

Answer (score 2):

**[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8Ecyd/)**

Add a `div` in html like this:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="panel">My Panel</div>
        </div>
       <div class="right">Blue</div>
       <div class="new_div">New</div>      <-- Added this new div here 
</div>
```

and use this CSS:

```
.new_div { background-color: white; width:320px; float: right;  }
```

Comment: What yellow div are you talking about?

Comment: Fiddle in my answer gives you desired result, isn't it?

Comment: The one you provided won't work so I creted the above fiddle to show you where it's going wrong.  I need the yellow div to show right under the blue.  Using your code it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="panel">My Panel</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="underright"></div>
</div>
```

```
.under_right {
    width: 320px;
    height: 100% auto; 
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: gold;
    float: right;
}
```

As long as the div .underright is underneath div .right, the float will obey that structure.

**Edit** Just a quick note, perhaps adding display: block; to the css will help, especially if you change the size of the outer container.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta name="" content="">
<style type="text/css">
.container {
    background-color: #000;
    margin: 130px auto;
    min-height: 320px;
    width: 940px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0px 10px;
 }

.left {
    width: 600px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    float: left;
 }

.right {
    width: 320px;
    height: 100% auto; 
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: blue;
    float: right;
}
.under_right {
    width: 320px;
    height: 100% auto; 
    overflow: auto;
    margin-top:30px;
    background-color: gold;
}

.panel {
    background-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="panel">My Panel</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="under_right">It is under right.</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```